# How to set up SKSpriteNodes: as a class or directly in a method of the SKScene?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skscene

I'm making a simple game and I have a 'noobish' question. If I want to create a SKSpriteNode (gem), should I create a class called gem, there create a method that creates the gems or should I create that method in the main SKScene that I'm using?

Simply: Should a Scene have the methods to create the SpriteNodes or it would be better to create a class for each one and then create an instance of the class in the Scene?

Thanks!

Comment: depends on what gem does and how it's being used in your game - either way works

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Well, a gem just falls from the sky and the user has to collect it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to use function or method in SKSpriteNode(gem) on the SKScene

suppose you create function/method

```
func initwithBackgrounds(files : NSArray , sizeover size:CGSize , pointsperSecondSpeed pointspeed:Double ) -> AnyObject{

        _pointsPerScndSpeed = pointspeed
        _numberImgForBg = files.count
        _backgrounds = NSMutableArray(capacity: _numberImgForBg)
        _randomizeDuringRollover = false


        files.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock { (obj: AnyObject!, idx: Int, stop: CMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> () in
           // if let node: SKSpriteNode = obj as? SKSpriteNode {
                // you can do something here with the node...
           // }
            var node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: obj as? String)
            node.size = size
            node.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
            node.position = CGPointMake(size.width * CGFloat(idx), 0.0)
            node.name = "BGNode"
            self._backgrounds.addObject(node)
            self.addChild(node)
        }

        return self
    }
```

this function use in SKScene is

```
let gemObj = gem()
gemObj.initwithBackgrounds(bgImageName, sizeover: pSize, pointsperSecondSpeed: 10.0)
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! The only thing is that in the Scene you have to use self.addChild(gemObj.initwithBackgrounds(...)) because otherwise it would not work.